# mvc 3 return view with other objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, object

I have a details page that returns a **profile** view that is basically used to find the page number from the database. I also have a separate query that I would like to return in the **return view** but cannot figure out how to. The code I have is

```
public ActionResult detail(int id)
    {
        profile profile = db.profiles.Find(id);
        var currentpage = (from s in db.profiles where id == s.profileID select s.registrationID).FirstOrDefault();
        var articles = (from s in db.Articles where currentpage == s.RegistrationID select s.title).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.articles = articles;


        ViewBag.noprofiler = " This profile currently doesn't have the email profiler selected";




        return View(profile);
    }
```

i would like to also return **articles** i put it into a **viewbag** but that is not working any ideas ?

Comment: articles should be available if you add it to the ViewBag, as long as it was assigned a value in the controller. Maybe something is wrong with the code you used in the view to access articles from the ViewBag. Can you past the view code you used to do this that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

If articles is populated then you should be able to access it in the view via ViewBag.articles

Maybe you should check what is in the articles variable here in the controller function.

Also the variable name articles suggests you're looking for a list but you are using FirstOrDefault() which would return a single object (or null).

Comment: oh ok but for me to get a list i would have to use the .tolist method which then I would need to make my model an ienumerable but that gives me an error as the return for "profile" is singular

Comment: you wouldn't need to make the model an IEnumerable. You can put anything into the ViewBag and still have a profile as the model. So you can use .ToList() and put the list in ViewBag.articles and then use the list of articles in your view.